# Easiest way to create simple 3d ios app

Tags: ios, ipad, 3d, modeling

I'm looking to create a simple iOS app (for a geometry class) where you can tap and drag around 3d figures (cylinders, cubes, triangular prisms, etc.). What would be the easiest way to do this? Note I don't know any Objective-C.

Comment: Study Objective-C. Then study OpenGL. Then go for it.

Comment: Wish I had the time to do that, but by then this class would be over.

Comment: If you don't have time to study Objective-C then I'm afraid you'll have a hard time finishing this app before the class ends regardless, as any solution will require some Objective-C. Looking at your profile you seem to have some experience with HTML and Javascript. Why not try something along those lines?

Comment: It's hard to reconcile creating a 3D app with the idea of not using Objective-C.  If the language/toolkit/'thing' you're looking for existed, how would you imagine interacting with it to create your app?  (I guess I'm partly asking whether you're looking for 3D modelling software rather than an app creation tool.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you download before april 8 2012 you get a free version of unity 3d ios version (android too if you are interested)

Answer (score 2):

It's kind of early but check out cocos 3d.  Cocos 2d is a popular 2D game platform.  Cocos 3D should insulate you from OpenGL ES.

http://brenwill.com/cocos3d/

> Both cocos3d and cocos2d are built on top of the OpenGL ES frameworks
>   that runs on all iOS devices, and both are written in the native
>   Objective-C familiar to all iOS developers. With cocos3d, you can
>   effortlessly create a full 3D game or application without getting into
>   the nitty-gritty needs of the OpenGL ES state machine, and without
>   having to switch over to C or C++, as required by most other 3D
>   frameworks.

There's a mashup sample project to illustrate how to use it's APIs.

> ... the cocos3d distribution contains a Demos folder, where you
>   can build and run the CC3DemoMashUp app, a more sophisticated sample
>   of what’s possible with cocos3d

Here's the programming guide:

http://brenwill.com/2011/cocos3d-programming-guide/